# using jquery infinite scroll to auto load set number of tumblr pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, tumblr, infinite-scroll

Lots of tumblr themes come with the jquery infinite scroll plugin. However, the maximum photos per page is 15 which is too small for my taste. How could I modify the jquery to auto load 2 or 3 pages at once?

site: http://asnip.tumblr.com

Comment: you will have to put a link to some source code, to get this resolved

Comment: as far as i can see you send an ajax request to any server .. this server is giving you back the 15 pix.. i guess you have to change it in any server side script

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just execute 3 ajax requests for the next 3 pages? (sorry, would comment but rep isn't high enough....) when the ajax returns with the results, append them to your page/list/object, whatever you're using to store your results

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the post count in the admin, as far as I remember, the default is 15.
[Example](http://academyoftumblr.tumblr.com/post/5578788270/changing-number-of-posts-to-show-on-your-blog)

Comment: As the OP states, the maximum is 15. (And the default is 10 btw).